# "Metadata Rejected" because ads could not be found on new version?

Tags: ios, metadata, iad

I searched and couldn't find an answer to this.

I submitted an app that has ads and got approved smoothly. I downloaded it from the app store and it shows ads. It was time for a new version so I release a new version but this time, it was rejected because they say that ads can't be found even though they show perfectly on my iPhone.

It said that a new binary is not required and I should just change the metadata (which I have no idea what that means). It said I didn't have to submit a new binary, so all I do is save any changes I did (which were none), and submitted again for review thinking it was maybe just an error.

This was part of the first error.

> To revise the metadata:
>
> - Log in to iTunes Connect
> - Click on “My Apps”
> - Select your app
> - Revise the desired metadata values
> - Click “Save"
> - Once you’ve completed all changes, click the “Submit for Review” button at the top of the App Details page

I don't know what it means by "revise the desired metadata values" so all I did was submit it again.

Nope, it got rejected again for the same reasons, but the message was different this time:

> We found that your app uses the iOS Advertising Identifier but does not include ad functionality. This does not comply with the terms of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, section 3.3.12 of the iOS Developer Program License Agreement states:
>
> You and Your Applications (and any third party with whom you have contracted to serve advertising) may use the Advertising Identifier, and any information obtained through the use of the Advertising Identifier, only for the purpose of serving advertising. If a user resets the Advertising Identifier, then You agree not to combine, correlate, link or otherwise associate, either directly or indirectly, the prior Advertising Identifier and any derived information with the reset Advertising Identifier."
>
> Note: iAd does not use the AdSupport framework, ASIdentifierManager, or the Advertising Identifier. Therefore they are not required for iAd implementations and should not be included in your app for iAd support.
>
> If your app is serving ads, please:
>
> - Ensure that you have tested your app on a device, not just the simulator, and that you have removed all previous versions of your app prior to testing
> - Provide us the steps to locate ads in your app
>
> If your app does not serve ads, please check your code - including any third-party libraries - to remove any instances of:

```
 class: ASIdentifierManager
 selector: advertisingIdentifier
 framework: AdSupport.framework
```

> If you are planning to incorporate ads in a future version, please remove the Advertising Identifier from your app until you have included ad functionality.

The new version has all the same code as the first one that was submitted.

Comment: Do I have to choose that it doesn't use the ID identifier thing when submitting it? If I choose no, will it still display ads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using iAds, then select no when they ask about the ID identifier. You will still get ads through iAd. iAds don't use the Advertising identifier.

Comment: Thanks! At first I selected yes and the app got approved so I thought I had to select yes each time.